# Jump to iframe after it loads

Tags: php, forms, scroll

I have a [coupon page](http://visitreno.com/coupons) on my site. It works like this:
The coupon list is generated from a database and placed in a form. Each coupon has a submit button that loads the coupon in an iframe under the coupon list.
Does anyone know of a way to scroll to the iframe when a user clicks on a coupon submit button?

Comment: Why do you use an iframes in the first place?

Comment: Just personal preference. I'm not too fond of pop up windows or taking visitors away from the coupon list.

Comment: I have seen the source code of the link you posted. Kindly give an ID to the table and use this code snippet to scroll to the table.  $('#Table').get(0).scrollIntoView();

Comment: @RenoJohn There are better ways then iframes, if you are in charge of the source. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

For more clarity you should have posted some code. stackoverflow is all about code. Any how I am writing in some generic code, you can change it according it to your need.

```
$("#button").click(function(){ // fires up when the couponsubmit button is clicked
  $('#IframeDiv').get(0).scrollIntoView(); //scrolls to the div that contains Iframe
});
```

**And I am assuming that you are using JQuery in your project :)**

Answer (score 0):

Use anchor in the form action and then place the anchor above the iframe

Basic example:

```
<form name='so' action='test.php#anchor1' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a name='anchor1'></a>
```